# packer aws instance builder throwing error manifest has invalid value File does not exist or is not a file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I am using amazon instance builder for creating image out of AMI. I am passing all parameters correctly. But I dont know which value should I pass in --manifest. I am getting following error.

> amazon-instance: --manifest has invalid value
>   '/tmp/ami-257e6b5c.manifest.xml': File does not exist or is not a
>   file.

I am using following file for conversion.

```
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_access_key": "",
    "aws_secret_key": ""
  },
  "builders": [{
    "type": "amazon-instance",
    "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
    "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "source_ami": "ami-257e6b5c",
    "instance_type": "t2.micro",
    "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
    "account_id": "12345678",
    "bundle_upload_command": "sudo ec2-upload-bundle -b packer-images -m /tmp/manifest.xml -a access_key -s secret_key -d /tmp --batch --retry",
    "s3_bucket": "packer-images",
    "x509_cert_path": "server.crt",
    "x509_key_path": "server.key",
    "x509_upload_path": "/tmp",
    "ami_name": "packer-example {{timestamp}}"
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't replace the template, copy it from the docs and modify it.

```
sudo ec2-upload-bundle \
  -b {{.BucketName}} \
  -m {{.ManifestPath}} \
  -a {{.AccessKey}} \
  -s {{.SecretKey}} \
  -d {{.BundleDirectory}} \
  --batch \
  --retry
```

See [bundle_upload_command](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-instance.html#bundle-upload-command).

The reason you have to remove `--region` is because you have an old version of *AMI Tools*. I recommend that you try to install a newer version from source, see [Set Up AMI Tools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-up-ami-tools.html).

Comment: The manifest file will be generated at run time. We can't guess the value of that file, because it adds a random number in file name like image-1234.manifest.xml. So I used image-*.manifest.xml for manifest value and it worked.